# Converting from object[] always returns Type, not value

Tags: c#, arrays, types

I need my Criterion class to accept a variety of types in its constructor, and preserve both the original Type and the value of each.  The number of parameters in this term can range from 0 to whatever.

```
/* Examples of calls:
   var c = new Criterion("IsActive", OperationCode.EQUALS, false);
   var c = new Criterion("AgeRange", OperationCode.BETWEEN, 18, 35);
*/

public Criterion(string fieldName, OperationCode op, params object[] value) {
    string FieldName = fieldName;
    OperationCode Op = op;
    object[] Value = value;
    string display = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", FieldName, Op, Value[0]);
}
```

In every case, elements of Value return **System.String[]**, not their value. For the first example call, display will be set to **IsActive EQUALS System.String[]**. Convert.ToString(Value[0]) does not help, nor does **.ToString()**. Ideas?

EDIT #1: Dmitry S suggested a test which opened an avenue of exploration.  I am calling Criterion with "false" as the only value[] argument.  In the Immediate Window, printing value.GetType() reveals that it is, as expected, an Object[].
value[0].GetType() reveals it to be a String[].  While it is originally a string, I have no ideal why .IsArray is true in this case.
When I call it with the integer 14, value[0].GetType() reveals a non-array Int32.
So far, the typing makes sense.  But I am interested in retrieving the **value**, not the type.

Comment: Try without `object[] Value = value;`, simply value[0]

Comment: Are you sure? I run your code and it's work as you expected. Use this : `string display = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", FieldName, Op, Value[0]);` NOT this : `string display = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", FieldName, Op, Value);`

Comment: Are you getting value from your parameter and make a null check for your value .....

Comment: Make sure you are not passing a nested array - object[] as the first value of the `value` parameter array. What does `Value[0].GetType().Name` return?

Comment: Thanks, all!  Dmitry S: Value[0].GetType().Name returns 'String[]'.  This put me on to find some other Type info, which I detailed in my Edit, above.  No answers, but at least a path of investigation!

Comment: Are you sure that you posted all relevant code? I.e. any chance you are actually using reflection to call constructor? Or any of local variables are actually properties?

Comment: I tried given code but getting expected result. i.e. I am getting actual value of Value[0] instead of its type!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
string display = String.Format("{0} {1} {{{2}}}", FieldName, Op, string.Join(", ", value));
```

if your array looks like

```
int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

it will show:

```
"field Equals {1, 2, 3, 4}"
```

*EDIT*

if your values can be also arrays, you may want to use a recursive method:

```
private string GetValueAsString(object obj)
{
    if(obj == null) 
         return "(null)";

    if(obj is IEnumerable)
    {
         var values = ((IEnumerable)obj).Cast<object>();
         return "{" + string.Join(", ", values.Select(GetValueAsString)) + "}";
    }

    return obj.ToString();
}
```

This will return

- "2" for 2
- "Donut" for "Donut"
- "{1, 2, 3}" for an array with the values 1, 2 and 3
- "{{"Donut", "Pie"}}" for an array that has an string array in the first element, with values "Donut" and "Pie"
- "(null)" if the value is null

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have your full source, the following imported into a blank project worked as described with minor changes, even on strings and arrays of strings, without mixing the two up:

```
class Program
{
    // not sure which other operations, so I just included these two
    public enum OperationCode { EQUALS, BETWEEN }

    // made class since it was used that way in your examples
    public class Criterion
    {
        // these have to be declared in the class, instead of the constructor to persist
        public string FieldName;
        public OperationCode Op;
        public object[] Value;

        // made this a property so that it will change automatically with FieldName, Op, and Value
        public string display { get { return String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", FieldName, Op, Value[0]); } }

        // constructor
        public Criterion(string fieldName, OperationCode op, params object[] value)
        {
            FieldName = fieldName;
            Op = op;
            Value = value;
        }
    }

    // main program tests with different values
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Criterion c;

        c = new Criterion("IsActive", OperationCode.EQUALS, false);
        Console.WriteLine(c.display);
        Console.WriteLine(c.Value[0].GetType().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();

        c = new Criterion("AgeRange", OperationCode.BETWEEN, 18, 35);
        Console.WriteLine(c.display);
        Console.WriteLine(c.Value[0].GetType().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();

        c = new Criterion("TitleString", OperationCode.EQUALS, "This is the title.");
        Console.WriteLine(c.display);
        Console.WriteLine(c.Value[0].GetType().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
IsActive EQUALS False
System.Boolean

AgeRange BETWEEN 18
System.Int32

TitleString EQUALS This is the title.
System.String
```

If you want `display` to show the whole array, then use `"[" + String.Join(", ", Value) + "]"` or similar instead of `Value[0]` inside the `get` block of `Criterion.display`, as per ivowiblo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Compiled and ran the following modified code on VisualStudio 2010:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{


    public class Criterion
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // your code goes here
            var c = new Criterion("IsActive", OperationCode.EQUALS, false);
            c = new Criterion("AgeRange", OperationCode.BETWEEN, 18, 35);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }


        public Criterion(string fieldName, OperationCode op, params object[] value)
        {
            string FieldName = fieldName;
            OperationCode Op = op;
            object[] values = value;
            object val = values[0];
            string display = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", FieldName, Op, values[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(display);
            Console.WriteLine(values[0].GetType().Name);
            Console.WriteLine(values.GetType().Name);
            Console.WriteLine(val.GetType().Name, val);
        }

    }

    public enum OperationCode
    {
        EQUALS,
        BETWEEN
    };

}
```

Output as expected:

```
IsActive EQUALS False
Boolean
Object[]
Boolean

AgeRange BETWEEN 18
Int32
Object[]
Int32
```